# OSM - Extract Street Name, Lat/Long, and City

Tags: xml, json, csv, openstreetmap

I'm learning how to work with OpenStreetMaps at the moment. I've just downloaded the latest [OSM for Quebec](http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/canada/quebec.html). I'd like to extract the street names, with the lat/long, and city for each one. I've seen a couple docs on using osmconvert and osmfilter, but honestly can't wrap my head around it.

I don't mind the format that it outputs, whether it being XML, CSV, or JSON (JSON preferred). What would be the best way to go about executing thing? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you realize that streets do not consist of a single lat/lon coordinate, but of multiple consecutive ones? And that streets may span across several cities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the standard tools that you mention, and [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) which will be handy for selecting just the streets from your export.

For postprocessing the XML into CSV or whatever, there are various routes. A while ago I wrote something which is hopefully small and grokkable: [a simple XSLT transform to extract pub names and lat/lon from an OSM file into a CSV file](https://github.com/danstowell/pubdensity). It does exactly what you ask for, except that it doesn't identify the city for each point.

If you look at the XSLT file linked in there, you'll see that there are some hardcoded pub-related things such as

```
<xsl:when test="tag[@k='amenity'][@v='pub']">
```

Change those to the things you want, e.g.

```
<xsl:when test="tag[@k='highway'][@v='secondary']">
```

and you'll be able to extract data with a command like:

```
xsltproc osm_streets_csv.xslt quebec.xml > quebec_streets.csv
```

In order to find the city for any given lat/lon, you can use the [MapIt Global service](http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/).